# Attach one element's event handlers into another in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this part.

```
<input id="text1" type="text" name="text1" onchange="alert('valueA');" /><br />
<input id="text2" type="text" name="text2" /><br />
```

What I'd want to do is to get the onchange event handler of the input="text1" and attach to another element's event, "text2".
So far , it's okay.I can get DOM0 hanlder of input "text1" and attach to text 2 as DOM2 .

```
_handler= $('#text1')[0].onchange;
            $('#text2').change(function (event) { 
            if (typeof _handler=== "function") {
                        _handler.call(this, event); 
            }
```

But, the problem is , I want to change/add some js codes before attaching into "text2".
For example ,  before attaching into "text2", I want to change "alert('valueA');" into "alert('valueA.This is text2')";
How can I do to achieve this?
The alert statement is just the example ,and please don't give solutions something like storing alert message into global variable, show the variable's value..etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done. You cannot change the code inside of a function.

Although Javascript functions are mutable objects, you can only add properties and methods to them, but you can't change the code inside of 'em.

---

If you want to use the evil `eval` (as you've specified in the comments), you could convert the function to a string, replace whatever text you want inside the function, and then eval it:

```
$('#text2').change(function (event) { 
    eval(
        '(' + $('#text1')[0].onchange.toString().replace('valueA', 'valueB') + ')()'
    );
});
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A4w2W/

But, **please please please don't do this.** This is the worst possible way to write code, **ever**!!
You should seriously reconsider your approach to this whole matter.

Comment: Agree. How about if I will NOT change them directly??? What I am thinking is to convert the function into string, replace it , convert back into function. Is it possible? something like eval()??

Answer (score -1):

Technically, no. But there are other solutions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
alertvalue = "valueA";
//-->
</script>
<input id="text1" type="text" name="text1" onchange="alert(alertvalue);" /><br />
<input id="text2" type="text" name="text2" /><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#text2').change(function(event) {
        alert(alertvalue + '. This is text2');
});
</script>
```

Comment: My requirement, though it sounds insensible, is NOT as simple as what you think.My onchange event handler can be anything.As I mentioned in my question, I give alert statement as just an example. Sometimes , it can be alert(). Sometimes, it may be some expressions.

Comment: Then my solution still stands. Using global variables, or variables created in closures, you can have dynamic functions. Evaluating a string is impractical (as it gets messy very quick) and is very hard to do. Also, in many browsers, string evaluation is slow.

Comment: If you check my question carefully, I have already mentioned not to give solutions something like using global variables.
I know there're better solutions other than string evluation. Something like creating parameters in the functions, and pass into it accoringly to make it behave differently. But, for some reasons, I can't apply it .